# Host MVC web app without IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a Asp.net MVC 3 application which I want to give to a user to use without them having to host it in IIS to run.

What I would like to have is some sort of executable that they click or a service which will host the application and then they can use it from any browser on the network.

What are my options?

Comment: But MVC is a web app, it can't be used this way. It should be hosted in some server.

Comment: Hi. Have you solved this issue finally? I want to do something similar, but running web application locally, on the same machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked into IIS [Hostable Web Core](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core.aspx)?

> This feature basically allows you to host the entire IIS functionality
>   within your own process. This gives you the power to implement
>   scenarios where you can customize entirely the functionality that you
>   want "your Web Server" to expose, as well as control the lifetime of
>   it without impacting any other application running on the site.

Comment: Hi Curt, not sure if you have used this, I ran the code provided, entered the directory to where my web page is (just some static page) but keep getting "page not found" in the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft style. It requires IIS7 to be installed locally :) What's the point of embedding a server already installed/running? Makes it pretty pointless.

Comment: I wouldn't say makes it pointless, but thanks for mentioning the requirement.

Comment: Setting up IIS application config is so complicated, you will eventually write a web server before you can successfully configure it.

Comment: @AaronLS it sort of does - e.g. these days you might want to deploy to Linux, and this sort of silliness stops it.

Answer (score 6):

You can look into IIS Express http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/ Although it is still IIS it's much lighter weight and might be what you need:

- It doesn't run as a service or require administrator user rights to perform most tasks
- IIS Express works well with ASP.NET and PHP applications
- Multiple users of IIS Express can work independently on the same computer.

Comment: By default, I do not believe that IIS Express can be accessed from machines other than the one it is running on. Here is a link that might show you how to get it to work (I haven't tried it myself): http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If the application is meant for production use, you need to host it under an IIS environment.  IIS Express is intended as a development server and not for production use.

Otherwise, IIS Express is the way to go if you want someone else to work on it in a local development environment.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following example.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

http://owin.org/

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

http://blog.micic.ch/net/owin-and-razor-enabled-mvc-application-framework

Regards