# Is it possible to self-host the asp.net mvc application without the use of IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, self-hosting

I am working in a small asp.net mvc application , so i want to self host this application without the help of IIS because i know IIS is not a light weight process.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709324/host-mvc-web-app-without-iis  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using an [OWIN](http://owin.org/) self hosted application - see [Use OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

There's also the option of IIS Express if you want something more lightweight.