# Can't able to refer the hwebcore.dll from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\hwebcore.dll to visualstudio2013

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, model-view-controller, dll

I am trying to host MVC web application without IIS in windows8. So i referred this link [Host MVC web app without IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709324/host-mvc-web-app-without-iis)

But i can able to add hwebcore.dll file into visual studio it show error like:

ERROR:

```
please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or com component
```

i referred the below link but nothing worked for me.

[I want a solution for this : Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/i-want-a-solution-for-this-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-th)

[.dll file not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582484/dll-file-not-accessible)

Answer (score 0):

This dll is not a .NET assembly, that's why you can't add a reference to it. What you can do is invoke its exported functions, like WebCoreActivate and WebCoreShutdown. See the example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx