# Possible to host a simple website from within a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have an existing product that runs in .Net 4.5.1 as a windows service. It currently hosts some WCF services for controlling and reporting on the product.

I now have a requirement to host a basic web application (ideally ASP.Net, but HTML and JS would do) within the windows service as well, for configuring the product.

We ideally don't want a separate install of a website/IIS as a requirement, so I really need to be able to do all this from the windows service itself. I will be calling into the WCF methods for some functionality, but I would ideally be able to run some .Net C# code as well.

I've looked about and all the stuff I find is for hosting web services within a windows service, or incredibly old stuff from 2010 or before.

I've looked into the ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost stuff, but the one tutorial I found involved adding stuff to the GAC, setting windows environment variables etc, which again, I would rather avoid and keep my stuff all fairly isolated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709324/host-mvc-web-app-without-iis

Comment: Have you had a look at the OWIN self-hosting features? http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/

Comment: Or look at node.js...

Comment: @BrianMains I wonder how you'd get node.js running inside a .NET Windows Service, which was the requirement here...

Comment: I think you would have to host your own HTTP server inside WCF Service. You can start here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx